# Locating Math Book

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, voting-theory

I am seeking the title of a math book I read several years ago and found interesting. It was intended for a general public audience and covered topics from Arrow's Voting Theorem,  Hilbert's Hotel (and other related set theory concepts), the traveling salesman problem, etc.

I fear that this may not be enough information to identify the book, but I hope it will.

Comment: Just curious, did you find the book, and, if so, what was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Books turned up](https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&aq=f&oq=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&aqs=chrome.0.57.13530&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=Clo9UcbrD9Hy0QHyo4GIAQ&ved=0CA8Q_AUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ&fp=10fa2e06c9462416&biw=1033&bih=536):

- James B Stein, "[How Math Explains The World: For Car Repair to Modern Physics](http://books.google.com/books?id=wN2oBA1LDD8C&lpg=PA255&dq=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)"
- Michael Clark, "[Paradoxes from A to Z](http://books.google.com/books?id=XCMxIZH69EgC&lpg=PP1&dq=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)"
- David Foster Wallace, "[Everything and More: A compact history of infinity](http://books.google.com/books?id=jZHanN5_KPgC&lpg=PP1&dq=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)"
- Aufmann, Lockwood, Nation, "[Mathematical Excursion](http://books.google.com/books?id=GTgTnSGMukgC&lpg=RA1-PA47&dq=arrow%27s%20voting%20theorem%20hilbert%27s%20hotel&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)"

Only the last one showed up when searching:

> arrow's voting theorem hilbert's hotel traveling salesman

Answer (score 0):

These are what I could find. From the 'Look Inside' feature, both books contain Hilbert's Hotel. You might want to look in the contents for other topics. Hope this helps.

http://amzn.to/ZxWXz3
http://amzn.to/VZdwUD